# \@ifnextchar's twin in the kernel

Tags: latex-base

In `latex.ltx` you can find

```
\let\kernel@ifnextchar\@ifnextchar
```

What was this needed for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was added due to this bug reported:

http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=AMS+LaTeX&pr=amslatex%2F3501

Comment: In *that* bug, it seems to reference [an earlier one](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=AMS+LaTeX&pr=amslatex%2F3471) where it was first detected.

Answer (score 17):

Some packages (particularly the AMS packages) redefine `\@ifnextchar`. Usually the redefined version has all of the properties of the original, but there are some places where the original is needed, which is what `\kernel@ifnextchar` is for.

If you look at the places where it is used, you'll find that it is mainly used in the definitions associated to `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` so that they always behave as intended.

The entire source of the `latex.ltx` is documented in `source2e.pdf` (available through `texdoc`).

Comment: So, the reason is somehow a democratic argument: Because *several* packages need to redefine `\@ifnextchar`, the decision was made to store a twin of it in `latex.ltx`.(?)

Comment: The documentation considers this a bug in the `amsmath` package: "It should really be fixed in the amsmath package one day, but..." (p.32) but since the `amsmath` packages are so widely used it makes sense to have the workaround, so that there exists an `\ifnextchar` macro that is guaranteed to work as originally intended.  I don't know if that's democratic.  It's certainly pragmatic.

Comment: @Ruben it is a late version of "this is a kernel command do not mess with it ..." of which there are only a few in LaTeX2e (unfortunately). It was an interface overwrite that should not have happened at least not everywhere.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach so the `ams` writers should have done someting like `\AMS@ifnextchar` instead of redefining the kernel command? (just to understand the direction of your comment)

Comment: @Ruben it is not that simple: the intention of the AMS was to make \\ not to skip spaces in their environments because that is often a source of error in math (if \\ picks up a * on the next line, say), In reality that is sensible for most environments (that's where the original spect of LaTeX have been sub-optimal). On the other hand there are cases where ifnextchar should skip spaces. So it is sensible to have both versions which we evenually did. However it would have been better if the AMS had kept the change confined to their environments.

Comment: @Ruben so we provided a "kernel" command and used it in the places where the space skipping is essential but kept \@ifnextchar in others so that the AMS package could overwrite those. We could not change those places ourselves as the officially documented behavior in the LaTeX manual is that spaces are skipped and modifying this for documents not using amsmath could have broken those. That's why the two are initially identical, but the intention here is to use \@ifnextchar in places where space skipping is potentially unwanted.